# Как правильно сделать релизную версию на Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, mingw

Переключил проект в режим выпуска, построил проект. 
После этого получившийся `exe-файл` требовал один `dll-файл` - `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` 
Я нашел соответствующий `dll-файл` в папке текущего компилятора MinGw 5.3.0 32bit, добавил в папку с проектом.
 В результате выдается ошибка `0x000007b`.

Answer (score 1):

Вам поможет

- специальный тул для Qt ([windeoloyqt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html))
- Универсальный [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/)
- Ручное исследование используемых приложением библиотек в процессе отладки (например, с помощью [Procerss Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx))

Comment: К сожалению windeployqt не помог, он не добавил правильную версию libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll - то есть ошибка сохранилась, даже когда я все перестраивал с нуля.

Comment: @просто_прогер попробуйте посмотреть зависимости. Рантайм компилятора вроде бы он не подтягивает.

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось, достаточно было посмотреть, **что именно**  загружает отладчик Qt. В Qt много библиотек с одинаковым именем, при том что версия одна.